# How many set of background pictures should I prepare for Android?

Tags: android

I would like to have a full screen picture when first load in the application.
However, there are some size and resolution of Android devices.
So, how can I prepare well to suit all devices and if I use imageview, what techniques should I use to make the pictures match the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this doc

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

1. 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800
   hdpi, etc).
2. 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
3. 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
4. 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).